# Building Apache Flink from source fail when package flink-1.5.2

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink

I just start my flink learning the day before yesterday.And I download the newest version of flink ----flink1.5.2
I run `mvn clean package -DskipTests` on both win10 ubuntu14.0 MacOS10.13,and both failed.By the way,I can not download code on the link`https://github.com/apache/flink.git`.Followed README.md, I can not build successfullly.

Here is the error info below:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flink-runtime 1.5.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] Deleting /Applications/yanjiusheng/examples/flink/flink-1.5.2/flink-runtime/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.5:revision (default) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- directory-maven-plugin:0.1:highest-basedir (directories) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] Highest basedir set to: /Applications/yanjiusheng/examples/flink/flink-1.5.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] Source directory: /Applications/yanjiusheng/examples/flink/flink-1.5.2/flink-runtime/src/main/scala added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ flink-runtime_2.11 ---
[INFO] /Applications/yanjiusheng/examples/flink/flink-1.5.2/flink-runtime/src/main/java:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Applications/yanjiusheng/examples/flink/flink-1.5.2/flink-runtime/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1451 source files to /Applications/yanjiusheng/examples/flink/flink-1.5.2/flink-runtime/target/classes at 1533878767045
[ERROR] error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/tools/ToolProvider
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.io.JavaToolsPlatformArchive.iterator(ZipArchive.scala:301)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.foreach(AbstractFile.scala:92)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.traverse(ClassPath.scala:277)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:264)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:358)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:269)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1535)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:256)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror$lzycompute(Global.scala:73)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:71)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:39)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1390)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1242)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:31)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:64)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[INFO]  at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:164)
[INFO]  at scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[INFO] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[INFO]  at scala_maven_executions.MainHelper.runMain(MainHelper.java:164)
[INFO]  at scala_maven_executions.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:26)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/tools/ToolProvider
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.io.JavaToolsPlatformArchive.iterator(ZipArchive.scala:301)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.foreach(AbstractFile.scala:92)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.traverse(ClassPath.scala:277)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.x$15(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:299)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.DirectoryClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:264)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath$$anonfun$packages$1.apply(ClassPath.scala:358)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
[INFO]  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages$lzycompute(ClassPath.scala:358)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.util.MergedClassPath.packages(ClassPath.scala:353)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:269)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$PackageLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:260)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1535)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.init(Mirrors.scala:256)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror$lzycompute(Global.scala:73)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:71)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global.rootMirror(Global.scala:39)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1390)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1242)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.doCompile(Driver.scala:31)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.MainClass.doCompile(Main.scala:23)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.process(Driver.scala:51)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Driver.main(Driver.scala:64)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
[INFO]  ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] force-shading ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.710 s]
[INFO] flink .............................................. SUCCESS [  2.077 s]
[INFO] flink-annotations .................................. SUCCESS [  1.585 s]
[INFO] flink-shaded-hadoop ................................ SUCCESS [  0.149 s]
[INFO] flink-shaded-hadoop2 ............................... SUCCESS [ 11.693 s]
[INFO] flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber .......................... SUCCESS [ 11.371 s]
[INFO] flink-shaded-yarn-tests ............................ SUCCESS [ 11.810 s]
[INFO] flink-shaded-curator ............................... SUCCESS [  0.827 s]
[INFO] flink-test-utils-parent ............................ SUCCESS [  0.117 s]
[INFO] flink-test-utils-junit ............................. SUCCESS [  1.006 s]
[INFO] flink-metrics ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.127 s]
[INFO] flink-metrics-core ................................. SUCCESS [  0.691 s]
[INFO] flink-core ......................................... SUCCESS [ 43.554 s]
[INFO] flink-java ......................................... SUCCESS [  7.657 s]
[INFO] flink-queryable-state .............................. SUCCESS [  0.098 s]
[INFO] flink-queryable-state-client-java .................. SUCCESS [  1.083 s]
[INFO] flink-filesystems .................................. SUCCESS [  0.131 s]
[INFO] flink-hadoop-fs .................................... SUCCESS [  1.078 s]
[INFO] flink-runtime ...................................... FAILURE [01:10 min]
```

info below are some Tests SKIP and the picture below

I have upload error information on this, hoping that I can get answer soon!

[image: this is the error info on Mac]

Comment: Please post the full error message as text (and not as image). There should be more error above the `BUILD FAILURE` line.

Comment: I have post the most of error message(stackoverflow does not allow post too much code)

Comment: Which java version do you use David Chan? The only version supported by flink right now is 8.

Comment: I'm using java8 and maven3.2.5.And now for some reason I build successfully which I don't know why....